# Uploading a file with PHP and moving it

Tags: php

I have a form where users can upload images. I know how to do it with HTML/PHP and I know that I have to move the temp file to the permanent directory. Well this all works well when my file that processes the form, is in the root directory. But, I would like to have it work within another directory, on the same server.

The Structure is this:

```
ROOT
    >images
    >mobile
        >upload.php
```

I would like to have the file put inside images, which is outside of the "mobile" directory.

My current upload path that does not work is:

```
define('UPLOADPATH', 'images/');
```

So essentially I need to go back one directory and then into images. How can I do this?

Comment: Use an absolute path?

Comment: I did not no that worked. Thank you

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/move_uploaded_file

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a .. To move to the parent directory.  See this [resource for more information](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm)